# How to select and display the specific row that match base on form inputs from PHP array?

Tags: php, html, database

I'm making school project for my Web development subject and this is the last part of my system that giving me a headache on how i'm going to do this. This part is most likely a search function with its few constant option( because I use dropdown list for inputs on my form). The goal of this part is to display the specific column on current page base on user input for the form. Lets say i have this fields on my **table1**

**| id | type | from | route | price |**

(The data that I need in this table is from "**price**" column only.)

Now on my php code, I retrieve all rows from my **table1** and store it on array. here is the code:

```
<?php
$sel = "SELECT * FROM table";
$res = mysqli->query($sel);
$Allrow = array();
while($rows = $res->fetch_assoc())
{
  $Allrow[] = $rows;
}
?>
```

Now on my html form which is where I want to display the specific data from **price** column on **table1**
here is the inputs:

```html
    <form action="status.php" method="post">
        <label>Type</label>
        <select id="type" name="tType">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="type1">Aircondition</option>
            <option value="type2">Ordinary</option>
            <option value="type3">Pickup</option>
        </select>
        <label>From</label>
        <input list="from" name="from">
        <datalist id="from">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="place1">Place 1</option>
            <option value="place2">Place 2</option>
            <option value="place3">Place 3</option>
        </datalist>
        <label>Route</label>
        <input list="to" name="to">
        <datalist id="to">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="place1">Place 1</option>
            <option value="place2">Place 2</option>
            <option value="place3">Place 3</option>
        </datalist>

        <p>Price: <!--Display column price here--></p>

        <input type="reset" name="Reset">
        <input type="submit" name="btn-submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Now, how do I display the specific data from my **$Allrow array** that meet the input data from my form.
This is the variable that holds input data:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn-submit']))
  $type = $_POST['type'];
  $from = $_POST['from'];
  $to = $_POST['to'];
?>
```

Please help me how I can achieve it on current page only. Because I achieve it by using separate page, and that is why ask here for help because my teacher want it to be on 1 page only without refreshing it, the price will display on form based on user input realtime.

Comment: You seem to have a typo: `mysqli->query($sel);`. I'm gussing it should be `$mysqli->query($sel);`

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple things here. How to filter the result based on the input and how to fetch and display those results without reloading the page. Please only ask one thing per question, or it will most likely just be closed for being unfocused.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson don't mind the query i just forgot type $ on that. Yeah your right about your second comment, Sorry if it's not clear. It is the best English I can speak.

Comment: When posting here, please make sure that the code you post doesn't contain new and unrelated syntax issues. You should really copy/paste your actual code instead of rewriting it here (for this specific reason).

Comment: Are you trying to show the route and price of the selected type?

Comment: @KevinGales No. i want to show the price of the selected route

Answer (score 0):

You could use **javascript** for that

```
<script>
document.querySelector("#isprice").addEventListener('input', function () {  //listen to the specific input with id isprice
  if(document.querySelector('#to').querySelector('option[value="'+this.value+'"]')){ //get values from options under datalist id to
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML="Price: KWD "+ this.value;   //display values on the paragraph id price
  }
});

</script>
```

Then in your **HTML** replace with

```
<label>Route</label>
        <input list="to" name="to" id="isprice">
        <datalist id="to">
            <option value=""></option>
           <?=$routes?> //list your routes-price pair as options
        </datalist>

        <p id="price">Price: KWD 0</p> // or you can leave it as <p id="price"></p>
```

In your **PHP** you need to create the option tags so that you can assign each route to its price

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1"; 
   $retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval)) {

         $routes .=  "<option value=\"".$row['price']."\">".$row['route']."</option>"; // assign prices to routes
      
   }
```